# Unordered_map Iterator Resulting in Seg Fault

Tags: c++, iterator, segmentation-fault, unordered-map

We have a line

```
mapOfMovies::iterator it = movie_map.find(name);
```

in our program that is for some reason resulting in a seg fault error. name is a string. mapOfMovies and movie_map are declared as follows:

```
typedef unordered_map<string, vector<Node*>> mapOfMovies;

class SomeClass {
 protected:

  mapOfMovies movie_map;
```

However, if we do something like `mapOfMovies::iterator it = movie_map.begin()`, it does not result in a seg fault error. When would `a .find(string a)` result in a seg fault error? I'm really confused and any help would be nice.

Thanks!!

Comment: When does the error occur, in funtion `std::unordered_map::find` or while dereferencing the iterator?

Comment: Your program has probably corrupted memory before you get to the line that seg-faults.  Use a debugger to watch the map and/or probe it from your code at intervals until you find the problem.

Comment: It occurs when the line "mapOfMovies::iterator it = movie_map.find(name); " is run

Comment: This is strange. You need to show more code around that. Or preferable minimal example that reproduces the problem. To prepare minimal example, gradually remove some parts of code as long as you are able to reproduce the issue.